# Single layer perceptron training?

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

I have been trying to train the following network and get suitable weights, but it keeps on running. Can anyone tell me what could possibly be wrong in the code? Here {8, 1} is input, {-1}} is expected output using a signum function.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ANN {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        double threshold = 1.2;
        double learningRate = 0.08;

        // Init weights

        double[] weights = { -1.4, 1.8 };

        int[][][] trainingData = {
            {{8, 1}, {-1}},
            {{3, 2}, {-1}},
            {{6, 3}, {-1}},
            {{1, 4}, {-1}},
            {{9, 5}, {1}},
            {{5, 6}, {1}},
            {{2, 7}, {1}},
            {{4, 8}, {1}},
            {{7, 9}, {1}},
        };

        // Start training loop
        while (true) {
            int errorCount = 0;
            // Loop over training data
            for (int i = 0; i < trainingData.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("Starting weights: " + Arrays.toString(weights));
                // Calculate weighted input
                double weightedSum = 0;
                for (int ii = 0; ii < trainingData[i][0].length; ii++) {
                    weightedSum += trainingData[i][0][ii] * weights[ii];
                }

                // Calculate output
                int output = 0;
                if (threshold <= weightedSum) {
                    output = 1;
                }

                System.out.println("Target output: " + trainingData[i][1][0]
                        + ", " + "Actual Output: " + output);

                // Calculate error
                int error = trainingData[i][1][0] - output;
                System.out.println("Error:  " + error);
                // Increase error count for incorrect output
                if (error != 0) {
                    errorCount++;
                }

                // Update weights
                for (int ii = 0; ii < trainingData[i][0].length; ii++) {
                    weights[ii] += learningRate * error
                            * trainingData[i][0][ii];
                }

                System.out.println("New weights: " + Arrays.toString(weights));
                System.out.println();
            }

            // If there are no errors, stop
            if (errorCount == 0) {
                System.out
                        .println("Final weights: " + Arrays.toString(weights));
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT: I believe that the issue arises from the code snippet that calculates output. It should be flipped so that if the sum is greater than the threshold output is 1 and it's 0 otherwise.

```
    // Calculate output
                int output = 0;
                if (weightedSum > threshold) {
                    output = 1;
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run your code and added a line just before the (errorCount==0) check:

```
System.out.println(errorCount);
```

This appears to oscillate between 6 and 7, which means that the Neural Network always generates invalid estimations of the Training Data regardless of the amount of training done.  If the training does not ever reach 100% correct for training data, then this is expected to last forever.

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your error can be positive and negative. In the first run, the error is -1. Hence, the errorCount is incremented and the code for exiting the loop is never executed.

The condition for complete training should be based on the error itself, not an errorCount. When the error reaches a minimum level (that you will set based on your inputs), the training will be considered completed.